# Comparing data from two data tables

Tags: c#, optimization

I have this code which compares data from two data tables.  It does this by using a primary column and inserting the new record from `table2` to `table1`. This loop continues for a large number of tables. I want to optimize it. Kindly give suggestions.

```
foreach (DataRow drRow in table2.Rows)
{
    if(!table1.Rows.Contains(drRow["KeyId"]))
    {
        table1.ImportRow(drRow);
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of .net framework is being used ?

Comment: Hi purnil, its 3.5

Comment: I think that this might be the best way to do it. I have done a little bit of looking and it seems like the other ways that I have thought about doing it fall short of this code.

Comment: Malachi, thanks a lot for looking into it. I too trying to find other way which will be more optimized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For .net framework 3.5, you can have following code improvements:

```
foreach (var drRow in table2.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                      .Where(drRow => !table1.Rows.Contains(drRow["KeyId"]))) 
{
    table1.ImportRow(drRow); 
}
```

1. part of body can be converted to LINQ-expression
2. use "var" (implicitly typed) instead of "DataRow" (explicitly typed)

Comment: Hi Purnil,I tried and i was not able to see any improvement in performance. In fact the old code was faster. Anyways thanks for your inputs :)